# Deploying database using TFS Deployer and SqlPackage

Tags: sql-server, powershell, deployment, tfs

I'm trying to make PowerShell script that uses `SqlPackage` to deploy database through [TFS Deployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/) service. Script is working if it is executed directly from command line but it fails when TFS Deployer tries to execute it, the same user account is used for both cases.

The service is running in test mode (`TfsDeployer -d`), as console application, but it also fails when runs as Windows Service.

This is log file (captured output of `SqlPackage` and exception caught in PowerShell script):

```
11/18/2012 17:51:49 | Publishing to database 'databaseName' on server 'machineName'.
11/18/2012 17:51:56 | An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
11/18/2012 17:51:56 | System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: *** Could not deploy package.
```

These are the only information I was able to collect. Error code (HRESULT) was not present in the caught exception.

PowerShell script goes like this:

```
try{
    $cmd = Join-Path (Get-Item "Env:ProgramFiles(x86)").Value "Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe"
    $src = Join-Path $source "db.dacpac"
    $cfg = Join-Path $source "db.publish.xml"

    &$cmd /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$src /Profile:$cfg 2>&1 | ForEach-Object -Process {
        Write-Log $_
    }
}
catch [Exception] {
    Write-Log $_.Exception.ToString()
    if($_.Exception.HResult) {
        Write-Log "Code: $($_.Exception.HResult.ToString('X'))"
    }
}
```